# Browsers keep scrolling up and down by themselves seemingly in random order

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I'm using a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows dual boot. For almost a month when I'm using my browser to read an article online or browse any long website, the page keeps jumping up and down seemingly in a random order. Surprisingly this problem is only there in Ubuntu and *not* in Windows. In Windows I can browse websites and read articles quite well, but in Ubuntu the problem is there in both Chrome and Firefox.

What I have done so far:

1.. My initial assumptions were that there might be dust stuck inside the keyboard and this is causing this issue. This is not true as the issue is only there for Ubuntu.

2. Just to make sure that there are no ghost keypresses or automatic mouse, trackpad movement I used several tools to monitor the keyboard and mouse activity as explained in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1646178/ghost-key-presses-in-dell-laptop): However I could not find any keyboard activity or trackpad movement.
3. In Ubuntu: the issue is not there when I'm writing a long word document in LibreOffice Writer or when I'm reading a long PDF file. The issue is *only* there for browsers (Firefox and Chrome).

What is the right way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I have this very problem. Are you using /etc/hosts to block ads? My problem only started once I started to use that. I am yet to test whether that's actually the problem

Comment: The most common issue is a second mouse connected at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit too late but posting it just in case someone has the same problem.
If you're not having hardware issues, you've probably enabled an accessibility option by mistake through a shortcut key, so just go to the accessibility options in settings and disable anything turned on by accident(probably the repeat key feature!).

Comment: Accessibility >> Screen reader for me.

Comment: It worked for me, too. I just off "Screen reader"

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but (assuming you are using Gnome) installing this extension seems to fix the issue:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5282/alttab-scroll-workaround/

This has been a known Chromium bug since 2017 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795 (VS Code uses Chromium))

I am not sure about Firefox though as it doesn't use Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Off your **Screen reader** in `Settings > Accessibility > Typing`.

It worked for me.