# sudden anomalies with scrolling in all browsers

Tags: mouse

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. No matter which of the three browsers I use, when scrolling down using the same mouse I have used 'forever", immediately upon scrolling down, the page suddenly jumps back up to the top.

On some pages, if I scroll down using the on screen scrollbar, this doesn't happen, and it seems to happen a little bit less if I have only one app running on screen at a time.

As you can imagine, it is driving me crazy, as it is not even consistent from one page to the next. FYI and FWIW, this does not appear to be happening on any other apps, beyond browsers...for example, scrolling in Thunderbird produces no problems.

The problem seems to happen less frequently if I am only using one workspace, but even then it still happens on some pages.

The problem happens with two different Logitech mice. Both are properly "registered" as bluetooth devices. One mouse has been used on this machine since 2020.

I have a theory that my problem is related to an update, because nothing else has changed since it was last working. Maybe there is some kind of new driver issue?

---

i am sorry to report that while what i have done as above, has reduced the incidence, it has not solved the problem...two separate mice are still running into the same problems, albeit on fewer web sites than before.

it is strange and erratic behavior, and I think it may have more problems with firefox than, say, the browser, Brave.

I am going to keep experimenting, but still conclude that this has to have had something to do wit a recent update...i religiously install them when they come from Ubuntu (I don't update browsers outside of ubuntu)....as this just started a day ago and I know I applied the most recent updates.

thank you for your comment.  additional observation (trying to be helpful here as well as to solve my problem):  Brave presenting far fewer issues than firefox, but settings on brave are more restrictive....javascript off by default, although when I put it on, on a site that has acted strangely, at first it gave me problems, but then turning it off and then on again, they went away. i understand this is all terribly anecdotal, but it might be that there is some interaction between whatever update has likely contributed to this problem and javascript, which on firefox on this box, is on by default. I will stay with it.....

update: working long hours with mission critical matters, jumping back and forth trying to do three things at one time, and failing to do them all well. I was hoping to get an answer rather than put up my own stream of thought, but i like to contribute where i can. that said, there are so many variables....browsers reacting the same but also differently...two different mice reacting the same but sometimes differently (as it concerns my problem) and the whole thing being an unwelcome distraction, but computers are what they are.  at this point, absent a big epiphany, I am going to drop back into the mist and hope that someone else can help me, as I cannot continue to work with this constant jumping around on the screen. my final comment for the moment is that I still think that javascript and some driver...maybe mouse or graphic..and a recent update.....are not acting well together, but things are sufficiently erratic such that I cannot be more definite than that, many thanks.
update: still a problem and erratic even from mouse to mouse. here is a link to other users and the same problems (unfortunately this does not help me yet, but it would appear to point to both a bug and what does work for some people:[Mouse wheel jumpy on scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32280/mouse-wheel-jumpy-on-scrolling)

Comment: I have a similar problem, where the scrolling jumps erratically in both Firefox and Chrome. Once the page loads completely the scroll jumping stops. I upgraded from Linux Mint 20.1 to 21 Vanessa and still have the issue.

Some have reported that there's a bug with Microsoft mice that can be resolved by plugging into a different USB port. I have a Logitech mouse and changing ports and changing mice had no effect.

Comment: If you're still having the problem after a year then check this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1455751/651078

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this that seems to work: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28795#issuecomment-1172222646

The solution is to install `imwheel` with this configuration:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=imwheel
Exec=/usr/bin/imwheel -b 4 5
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```