# Odd keyboard behavior

Tags: keyboard, firefox, mouse

I recently started having problems with my system. I am running Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic with Linux sxkd 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

It was working fine for some time [couple of weeks] but a few days ago started giving me grief. The keyboard behaves as if someone is pressing up and down arrows or page up/down or something like that.

Basically,

- in any website as I scroll down while reading, it jumps back to the top.
- numpad keys work sometimes and sometimes not - when I press them, the entry [like the text entry box here] blink.
- sometimes none of the keys register in the browser but if I click on a terminal and type, that works.
- Scrolling to the top only happens in browsers, especially firefox. Geany doesn't do that.
- Text entry in firefox also seem to lag quite a lot.
- Problem persists with external keyboard and the built-in laptop keyboard.
- Problem persists with or without external wireless mouse.
- Problem does not happen in Windows.
- Happens with and without external keyboard, with and without USB hub

xev shows the following when I press numpad 4.

- FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001, mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear
- PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001, atom 0x173 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 123563870, state PropertyNewValue
- PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,atom 0x1ce (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 123563870, state PropertyNewValue

I am a longtime Manjaro user who recently switched back to Ubuntu d/t Manjaro refusing to boot after an update. I am not sure what I did wrong here but would love to dig in deeper with guidance.

Any help on where to look will be greatly appreciated.
My suspicion is on the focus from GTK etc. I have been searching the net but the posts I came across are different enough. I tried some of the settings in firefox but then realized the problems are wider than firefox.

Comment: **Repeated issue:** [Issue Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340557/browsers-keep-scrolling-up-and-down-by-themselves-seemingly-in-random-order)